# SharePoint 2013 CSOM: How to attach an event receiver to a list

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, csom

A list has a (C#) event receiver. I would like to attach this (existing) event receiver to another list (actually multiple lists) using the SharePoint client object model (CSOM). Is this possible and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample of working with remote event receivers on PowerShell through CSOM. I hope this helps:

[Add/delete and list Remote Event Receivers with PowerShell/CSOM](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/01/add-delete-and-list-remote-event-receivers.html)